# Some process keeps trying to launch Outlook. How do I find out what it is and stop it?

Tags: windows-10, email, process

Randomly, and seemingly for no reason, a generic Windows message box will pop up saying there is no default mail client installed. I click OK and the message box goes away for several hours until it decides to come back. While the message box is active the process running in Task Manager is called "COM Surrogate (32 bit)" but I can't tell what started it, where it's coming from, or how to stop it.

Comment: Processmon may help but may not be the easiest https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: It could be malware, trying to use the PC to send spam. Have you performed a thorough AV scan, not only with your normal AV suite, but also using a stand-alone tool such as MalwareBytes or Kaspersky online scanner?